# Background of image turning black when using keras.preprocessing.image load_img

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras

my code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.preprocessing.image import smart_resize
import numpy as np

#load pretrained model
os.chdir('path/to/dir')
# model = load_model(model_path)
input_imagesX = natsorted(os.listdir())
for idx, v in enumerate(input_imagesX):
    
    img = load_img(v,color_mode='rgb')
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = tensorflow.image.resize(img, (128,128))
    # img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.grid(None)
    plt.show()
```

Here, the transparent background of the png turns black and the fill gets distorted. Have tried a couple of hacks, none seems to work!
Can someone please help?

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7W0r.png)

[image i get as the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbLJC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Some images might also have an alpha channel. Please find below how to load the alpha channel

```
img = load_img("/content/transparent.png",color_mode='rgba')
img = img_to_array(img)
img = tensorflow.image.resize(img, (128,128))
img=tensorflow.cast(img,tensorflow.int32) 
plt.imshow(img)
plt.grid(None)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!